# MS Office 2013 Email Rules : How Do You Stop Auto Printing Rule based on Subject Line?

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office

I'm used to coding and developing work, but recently I got a request to create actions in MS Office. I don't think that this needs a new script written, but I can be wrong. Just in case it's something more simple, I thought I'd just query here.  Here is the dilemma:

Person A has a few MS Office rules that say: If a new email is received with the name XYZ in the subject line, automatically print it.

This rule works as it should. However, when there is back and forth correspondence, the emails no longer need printing. Only the initial email should print automatically.  If Person A replies to the people at XYZ and they reply back or forward her a subsequent email, this should NOT print.

I had set up a new rule stating that if any emails are received with "RE:", "Re:" or "FWD:" in the subject line to "Stop processing more rules...".

However, all of Person A's emails started to print after this. I've removed the rule and I think that it may have only been a question of the priority in which the rule was listed. Meaning, that the new rule (catching emails with "RE:", "Re:" or "FWD:" in the subject line should have preceded all rules.

Is this the correct way to have handled this, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single rule which triggers a VBA macro if the subject contains a keyword. The VBA macro should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  '
End Sub
```

In the code you may check whether a subject string begins with the keywords or not. The [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) fuction returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

The [PrintOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861582(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class prints the Outlook item using all default settings.The PrintOut method is the only Outlook method that can be used for printing.